# How to change the border highlight color of a outlinebutton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

How do you change the border highlight color of a outlinebutton in flutter? I can set the color normally but as soon as someone presses it changes to blue. I tried giving it a highlight color property but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `highlightedBorderColor` property of the `OutlineButton`:

```
OutlineButton(
  child: Text('Press'),
  highlightedBorderColor: Colors.red,
),
```